# return common fields in two files

Tags: awk, unix

I have two files, should compare 1st column of file1 with 1st column of file2 and the resultant file should be file2

For example:

- file1

  apple
  banana
  Mango
  potato
  tomato
- file 2

  apple:fruit
  brinjal: vegetable
  lady's finger: vegetable
  orange: fruit
  tomato: vegetable
  potato: vegetable

Resultant file should look something like this:

apple:fruit
tomato: vegetable
potato: vegetable

any ideas on this would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without the need to sort (less process creation)

```
$ awk -F":" 'FNR==NR{f[$0];next}($1 in f)' file file2
apple:fruit
tomato: vegetable
potato: vegetable
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, ksh, zsh:

```
join -t: <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

In other shells you will need to presort your files.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "$(cat file1.txt)" file2.txt
```

Comment: `grep -f file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: @Shruti: what shell are you using? I did that in bash 4.1.5 and it worked.

Comment: i'm using C shell I have tried it in bash too, i'm getting the same error

Comment: @Shruti: Alberto's version won't work in csh, but the version in my comment should. You can also try this variation on Alberto's version: `grep "\`cat file1.txt\`" file2.txt`. It would be really weird if you're getting that error in Bash.

Comment: using grep may not be suitable since grep finds the whole line for the pattern.