# grep in two files returning two columns

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sh, comm

I have a big file like this:

```
79597700
79000364
79002794
79002947
```

And other big file like this:

```
79597708|11
79000364|12
79002794|11
79002947|12
79002940|12
```

Then i need the numbers that appear in the second file that are in the first file bur with the second column, something like:

```
79000364|12
79002794|11
79002947|12
79002940|12
```

(The MSISDN that appear in the first file and appear in the second file, but i need return the two columns of the second file)

Who can help me, because whit a grep does not work to me because return only the MSISDN without the second column
and with a comm is not possible because each row is different in the files

Comment: Similar question has been asked many times. Also what have you tried?

Comment: Similar to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822646/return-common-fields-in-two-files

Comment: How's `79002940` in output when it is not in 1st file?

Comment: Is it important to preserve the order of lines?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
grep -f bigfile1 bigfile2
```

Comment: Beware that if `bigfile1` contains a line containing just `3`, it will match a lot of lines that aren't wanted.  You might need to do something fancy with process substitution (`grep -f <( sed 's/.*/^&|/' bigfile1) bigfile2`) to ensure that the number in file 1 exactly matches the whole of the first field in file 2.

Comment: Yes, that's right. A workaround: `sed -n -f <(sed -n 's|.*|/^&\|/p|p' bigfile1) bigfile2`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `grep -x` will fix that.

Comment: @o11c: please explain how `grep -x` will help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it only matches whole lines ... wait, that won't handle the `|10` bit. Hm, `grep -w` maybe?

Comment: @o11c: Yup; `grep -x` wouldn't handle the pipe.  You could use `grep -w` and as long as the numbers after the pipe aren't confusable with the numbers before, it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F"|" 'FNR==NR{f[$0];next}($1 in f)' file file2
```

Source: [return common fields in two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822646/return-common-fields-in-two-files/3827042#3827042)